# Parole che iniziano/ terminano per o in?

Tags: verbs, prepositions

1a)Le parole che iniziano/ terminano per "a".

1b)La lettera per cui inizia/ termina la parola "mela" è proprio questa.

1c)Per quale lettera inizia/ termina questa parola?

2a)Le parole che iniziano/ terminano in "a".

2b)La lettera in cui inizia/ termina la parola "mela" è proprio questa.

2c)In quale lettera inizia/ termina questa parola?

Quali sono rispettivamente i complementi introdotti da "per" e "in" nelle precedenti frasi?

Per quanto riguarda "in" azzarderei che si possa trattare di complemento di luogo figurato, mentre per quanto riguarda "per" non saprei che dire.

Comment: Non ho mai sentito dire “comincia/termina _in_ a”. Dove l'hai trovato?

Comment: @DaG https://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=terminare

Comment: Ah, grazie. E per quanto riguarda “inizia” (ma classicamente si considerava più corretto “comincia”)?